# HttpPost generating results but not sending back to angular controller

Tags: json, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I’ve been battling this problem now for a few hours, and have tried several solutions (including using dataset, datareader to access the data, converting the datareader/dataset into a list of objects and then sending the result as a Json. I’ve also tried using Json.Net and a replacing the `$http` with an AJAX call, all to no avail.

In an MVC4 project, I’ve detailed an angular controller to retrieve data from our ACCESS database. An `$http` request is sent to the (local)server, received, and executed. The results generated, however, are not received back by the angular controller.

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated

This is the method:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetCatalogueItems(string get)
{
    JsonResult toReturn = null;                  
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connStringPT"].ConnectionString;
        OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(cs);
        string queryStart = " SELECT catNum, testName, price, comments FROM table_catalog WHERE ";

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {

            List<ptProductModel> listToReturn = new List<ptProductModel>();
            string query = queryStart + get + "=true;";
            cn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, cn);
            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    ptProductModel item = new ptProductModel
                    {
                        Number = reader[0].ToString(),
                        Name = reader[1].ToString(),
                        //comment = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("comments")) !=null ? reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("comments")) : null,
                        price = reader[2].ToString()
                    };
                    listToReturn.Add(item);
                }
                reader.Close();
                if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    cn.Close();
                }
                toReturn = Json(listToReturn.Select(s => new { Name = s.Name, price = s.price, Number = s.Number }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }              

        }

        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            toReturn = Json("Error", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }           
        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

And this is the angular controller:

```
myApp.controller('ptCatalogueController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.catalogueItems = [];
    $scope.Product = "";
    $scope.Init = function () { }

    $scope.GetProducts = function (productSet) {
        console.error(productSet, 'blabla');
        $http.post({
            url: '/Catalogue/GetCatalogueItems', data: { get: productSet }
        }).then(
            // success callback
            function (data) {
                $scope.catalogueItems = data;
                console.log($scope.catalogueItems);
                console.debug("success");
                }
                ,
             //error callback
            function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                console.debug("error");
            }
        )} 
}]);
```

and the header:

```
POST /Catalogue/[object%20Object] HTTP/1.1  
Host: localhost:49078  
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*  
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate  
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6  
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=fvfswezab5g1ekyiuotmpw3m  
Origin: http://localhost:49078  
Referer: http://localhost:49078/Catalogue/Index  
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like   Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36
X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id: 0689EBCB-E24D-48E3-ACF9-0D94BB0B6F16  

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found  
Cache-Control: private  
Content-Length: 3732  
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8  
Date: Sun, 22 Nov 2015 07:59:03 GMT  
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0  
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319  
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET  
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?  RTpcR2VuZXJhbCBGb2xkZXJcRGV2ZWxvcG1lbnRcV2ViLVBzeWNoVGVjaC1OZXdTaXRlXFdlYi1Qc3ljaFRlY2gtTmV3U2l0ZVxDYXRhbG9ndWVcW29iamVjdCBPYmplY3Rd?=
```

Comment: Do either "success" or "error" write to console? What does the network request response headers show?

Comment: @Jasen, the first time the request is executed, I get a success. All subsequent efforts result in error

Comment: Your url is not resolved properly `/Catalogue/[object%20Object]` and returns `404 Not Found`. Something from the view `/Catalogue/Index` made the request. How do you trigger the angular controller action? What does that view look like?

Comment: Also, review [`$http.post()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post) documentation. You're passing incorrect parameters.

Comment: @Jasen. thanks for your reply. the original request was made from the _Layout view using an a href ("/Catalogue/Index"). an ng-click in the same line fired up the GetProducts function in the angular controller, to get the items to populate the page. both views were using the same angular controller